# How to merge the tailing fields in a sorted result in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If the following command is executed, we could see that there are 6 results.

```
> select competition.region, count(competition.score) as cnt from competition group by competition.region order by cnt desc;

## --Result--
CN      80
USA     60
SE      40
US      10
JP      10
KR      8
```

But what I want is to merge the fields from 4th line to the end into a field called 'other':

```
## --Result--
CN      80
USA     60
SE      40
OTHER   28
```

Is there any way to achieve that in a single SQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a derived table to merge the others together:

```
select region, count(*) as cnt
(select case when competition.region in ('CN', 'USA', 'SE') then competition.region
             else 'OTHER'
        end as region 
 from competition) as dt
group by region
order by cnt desc
```

**Edit:**

Return 3 most common regions separately. The rest of them as OTHER.

```
select region, count(*) as cnt
(
 select case when region in (select region from competition
                             group by region
                             order by count(*) desc
                             limit 3) then region
             else 'OTHER'
        end as region
) as dt
group by region
order by cnt desc
```

Note that only one region will be returned if it's a 3:rd place tie.

Comment: the field of region (CN, USA, SE, ...) is dynamic, so we could not hardcode it in our SQL.

Comment: What I need is to retain merely the first three fields, with all the other fields merging into the 'other' field.

Comment: Oops, missed that detail. But how do I decide which 3 countries to chose? I mean, first 3 according to what?

Comment: According to the `order by desc` on field `count(competition.score) as cnt`. I only intend to show the first three country with the highest score, whereas the others merging into the 'other' field.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support cte's? Would have been convenient here. Wait a few minutes, and I'll be back.